# working with multiple tables

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a c# project where I am using a MS access database, and I am trying to put some items from two (related) tables, in the same listView.

This is the code that I have:
[image]

Where it sais "none" is the place where I want to put an item from the other table, but i don't know how. Since they have a relationship I thought that was possible to call items from one table or another.

Please note that I am fairly new to c# and working with databases.

Comment: You can copy/paste your code into your question, mark it and press Ctrl+K , to format it as `code` or manually click `{}` in the editor.
Plus: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read the [FAQ]

Comment: you need to create a query that joins the two tables & then you can add the required data as you are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select FirstName,LastName,(select none from SecondTable where Clients.Field= SecondTable.Field),CellPhone,ClientID from Clients
```

Answer (score 2):

You should join the two tables together to get the unified result.

You could do something like this:

```
select c.*
,      s.otherFieldYouNeed
from   ClientsT c
join   SomeOtherTable s
on     c.someId = s.someId
```

Comment: Depending on the number of columns in the table and how many of them that OP wants, they might not want to do `c.*` and rather specify only the columns from `ClientsT` that they need.

Comment: Indeed, but OP already does that and I don't want to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 1):

since the two table are related you can use a join query to get the desired result:

```
select FirstName,LastName,'none',CellPhone,ClientID from Clients inner join mySecondTable

on Clients.mysharedField=mySecondTable.mysharedField
```

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your query to include this information.  Something like:

```
  Select FirstName, LastName, ColumnFromOtherTable, CellPhone, ClientsT.ClientID 
from ClientsT, OtherTable where ClientsT.ClientID=OtherTable.ClientID
```

Of course, in order to do this, you have to have a corresponding ID field in both tables.